# Same log file for six tomcat instances hosted on single server

Tags: tomcat8

I have a setup in which six tomcat instances is running on single server on six different port.
to setup this i just download tomcat.tar file and extracted then changed the ports in server.conf
Now for some reason i want a single log file for all six of the tomcat.
How is this possible. can we use same catlina.out for all six tomcat instances.

Tomcat version is 8.and all tomcat instance run different application.

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution. Let me know if you find out, and I'll do the same

Comment: i was not able to get this done. what is it that you want to accomplish by single log file

Comment: To make it easier to debug when something goes wrong. I ended up having each instance create its own log files. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836175/two-instances-of-tomcat-on-the-same-machine-using-the-same-log-file/42847833#42847833