# Two instances of Tomcat on the same machine using the same log file

Tags: tomcat, log4j

I recently had an issue where my log files were not rolling over like they were supposed to as defined in my log4j config. I figured out that the culprit was that I have two instances Tomcat running the same app which both had a hold of the same log file, so neither one could roll it over because of the other one.

However, I would still like to use the same log file. I use two instances for load balancing and it would be annoying to have a log file for each instance.

Is there any way I can do this? Or am I doomed to have multiple log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would **not** recommend to use **same** log file for **multiple** applications.Because,

- it will be difficult to **read** log file.
- it will impact **performance**.

However, you can achieve this by using '[prudent](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#prudent)' flag from logback as below.

```
<appender name="FILE_PRUDENT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logs/test.log</file>
    <prudent>true</prudent>
</appender>
```

From official docs,

> In prudent mode, FileAppender will safely write to the specified file,
>   **even in the presence of other** FileAppender instances running in
>   **different** JVMs, potentially running on **different** hosts. The default
>   value for prudent mode is false.